# Azure command line 'az ml' on Mac not working

Tags: macos, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-cli

I am trying to run any `az ml` function and am running into this error:

```
$ az ml -h

az: error: argument _command_package: invalid choice: ml
```

I do not see any suggestion so far that gets ml to be a supported function for azure-cli. Looking if anyone can help.

Answer (score 2):

You need install Azure Machine Learning Workbench on macOS firstly, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/preview/quickstart-installation#install-azure-machine-learning-workbench-on-macos).

> Install Azure Machine Learning Workbench on your computer running
> macOS Sierra or later.
>
> Download the latest Azure Machine Learning Workbench installer,
> [AmlWorkbench.dmg](https://aka.ms/azureml-wb-dmg).

When you launch Azure ML Workbench and log in for the first time, and if you don't have access to an Experimentation Account already, you are presented with the following screen:

[image]

Click on the **Command Line Window link** in the dialog box to launch the command line window.

Then, you could use `az ml -h`
[image]

Note: I test it on Windows, maybe it is different with Mac.

More information please refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/preview/tutorial-iris-azure-cli).

Comment: Hi, does it work for you? You need download AmlWorkbench.dmg and install it firstly. I update my answer.